# Brandywine Maple?

Tags: botany

I'm collecting and classifying leaves for biology. Teacher took us on a 'walk' to help. She let us pick and told us one leaf was a Brandywine Maple and another later on, a different leaf, was a Red Maple. I'm googling around to classify, but everything says that a Brandywine maple IS a Red maple (different name).

What the?
Help please...

Comment: Perhaps you should talk to your teacher instead of asking strangers on the internets...

Comment: Wow. That was extremely helpful.

Not. What's the point of this site to students then? What if I want to finish this project this weekend before school starts again?

Not to be really harsh in tone. But I would appreciate an answer a lot more than that.

Comment: First, when your project is due is of no concern to us. If all of your research points to "Brandywine Maple" simply being another name for red maples, then perhaps you should speak to your teacher to find out why she was differentiating between the two. On the other hand, if the two leaves are clearly different, you should [edit] your post to include focused, well-lit, labeled images of each of them and a clearly-articulated question about them. *"What the? Help please..."* does not qualify, I'm afraid. You may want to take the [tour] and read the [help] to find out more about this site.

Comment: I'd also suggest reading our (rather brief, but to-the-point) [homework policy](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). We are not a homework service, but with enough thought and work from you, we may be able to help point you towards an answer.

Comment: @MattDMo I disagree that this is a poorly researched homework question. The OP has clearly made attempts at answering the question (see the googling line), which is backed up by my own search.

Comment: @MarchHo I never said it was a poorly-researched homework problem, nor have I voted to close it as such. I was simply pointing out our homework policy.

Comment: It was kind of implied, whether you meant to imply such or not, in your comment. I don't see why you would point me to the homework policy otherwise (If you wanted me to tag it homework, which I neglected to do accidentally, you coulda just said so).

Also, I'm not telling you to be concerned about the due date (it's in fact not due tomorrow, it was just an example, that), but I was irked by the fact you left a basically useless comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the Missouri Botanical Garden](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?taxonid=273746&isprofile=0&) and [Washington State University](http://www.pnwplants.wsu.edu/PlantDisplay.aspx?PlantID=725), *Acer rubrum* var. Brandywine is a [cultivar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultivar) of the red maple, *Acer rubrum*.

> 'Brandywine' is the result of a 1982 cross (Acer rubrum 'October
>   Glory' x Acer rubrum 'Autumn flame') conducted as part of a U. S.
>   National Arboretum research project. It was subsequently introduced
>   into commerce in 1995.

[...]

> As a cross of the red maple cultivars ‘October Glory’ and ‘Autumn
>   Flame’, the variant ‘Brandywine’ was released for its resistance to
>   leaf hoppers. It turns a burgundy color later in the fall than the
>   popular October Glory.
>
> As with other red maple cultivars this one does well on many different
>   types of sites. As such, red maple is well adapted to sites to that
>   are wet.

Therefore, you are correct to say that a Brandywine maple is a red maple. However, it is **not** the alternative name for a red maple. All Brandywine maples are red maples, but not all red maples are Brandywine maples.